# Show new state of attribute for each listitem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, get

I'm rendering a list of attributes (artists) in React. While rendering, a separate HTTP request has to be made for each list item to display additional information (genres). To solve this issue, I put an empty array in the state beforehand - to update this state for each item during rendering:

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
          newState.categoryList[item.id] = names; // names is a single string containing all genres
          this.setState(newState);
```

Eventually, I'm trying to display the genres (which are put into a single string) in a text field, after calling the method in the JSX: `{this._getCategories(item)}`.

```
/* this._getCategories is called to make an additional HTTP request for
         every item in the list. this.state.categoryList[item.id] should contain
         the required value (string). */
        {this._getCategories(item)}
        <Text style={styles.categories}>this.state.categoryList[item.id]</Text>
```

I've made a reproducible version on Expo.io, which can be found here: [Snippet](https://snack.expo.io/@jvdl2711/genres). To make things easier to understand, I added additional comments at each part of the code.

**Edit**

The problem appeared to be the way I used to update the state, which caused that the expected values weren't visible. The accepted answer has helped me to solve this.

Comment: Whenever you're setting new state based on existing state (as in your first code block), you **must** use the callback version of `setState` and the state object it passes you; you can't do it as you have above. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous This may actually be the problem, if the problem is that you're not seeing things get updated. But you haven't told us what the problem is. :-) You've described a situation, but haven't said what (if anything) isn't behaving as you'd like...?

Comment: Please put your runnable [mcve] **in** the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), so that all of the code needed to answer the question is **in** the question. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the problem you're having is that you're not seeing things get re-rendered when your HTTP requests complete, it's because you're breaking a React rule here:

```
// Incorrect
let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
newState.categoryList[item.id] = names; // names is a single string containing all genres
this.setState(newState);
```

Whenever you're setting new state based on existing state (as in your first code block), you **must** use the callback version of `setState` and the state object it passes you; you can't do it as you have above; [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

You've said `categoryList` is an array. From your description, it sounds like it's a *sparse* array (at least initially). When setting the state, you have to make a copy of the array containing the changes, you can't directly modify it. Since it seems to be sparse, we can't do it the usual way (with spread notation in a literal), we have to use `Object.assign` instead:

```
// Correct
this.setState(({categoryList}) => ({categoryList: Object.assign([], categoryList, {[item.id]: names})}));
```

or the possibly-clearer, verbose version:

```
this.setState(state => {
    const categoryList = Object.assign([], state.categoryList);
    categoryList[item.id] = names;
    return {categoryList};
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot for all the tips and for your helpful answer! It's working perfectly at the moment. Cheers :)